# What is $E$ in the Planck-Einstein relation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, energy

The Planck-Einstein relation was first given for photons

$$E = h\nu$$

But later, [de Broglie extended it to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%E2%80%93Einstein_relation#de_Broglie_relation) matter waves, and showed that it would hold for all particles as well. The $E$ for a photon is simple enough to define (the relativistic KE, if I'm right), but what is $E$ for other particles, say for an electron?

Is it the kinetic energy, potential energy, or total energy?

Comment: It is the total energy.

Comment: @lemon: Total energy as in mass-energy, potential energy, kinetic energy, everything included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right>}$
$\newcommand{bra}[1]{\left< #1 \right|}$
$\newcommand{bk}[2]{\left< #1  \big| #2 \right> }$
In the level of QM you really don't have kinetic energy and potential energy. Some likes to call the expectation value of the operator $\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}$ on the state $\ket{\Psi}$ the kinetic energy and the expectation value of the operator $V(\hat{x})$ on the state $\ket{\Psi}$ the potential energy. However they are not like the classical kinetic and potential energy.

The energy in this equation $E=\hbar \omega=h \nu$ is the total energy of the particle that you are talking about. For example for the harmonic oscillator you have $E=\hbar \underbrace{\omega_o \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}_{:=\omega} = \hbar \omega$, where $\omega_0$ is the angular frequency of the harmonic oscillator. From this you can see that $\hbar \omega$ gives the total energy.

Comment: So, for an electron, $E$ would be $mc^2$?

Comment: What do you mean by that? $E$ is always $mc^2$

Comment: What I meant was, in the formula ($E = h\nu$), for any particle I can substitute $mc^2$ for $E$, right? Sorry for the (probably) stupid question, but I'm new to QM.

Comment: I would say you can but I haven't studied relativistic QM so I don't want to mislead you by saying that you can. However it is often done in schools that they set these two equations equal and calculate stuff with it. How legitime that is, I don't know.

Comment: So, in this case, for an electron (say) I would simply set $E$ to be the total of KE (translational) + PE, right?

Comment: As I said above there is no PE or KE as you would expect in CM. Just accept $h \nu$ as *the* energy and don't mix (mix as in mixing a drink)it with the classical PE and KE.

Comment: How can you tell what the velocity of the particle is when your particle isn't like a bullet but it is more like a mush. Hence you cannot compute the KE with $mv^2/2$ anyways. As I emphasized over and over treat QM like QM and not like CM.

Answer (score 0):

It will be total energy . But it can be change with respect to condition.Suppose if you consider this free electron then the electron have no potential energy .Only kinetic energy will remain.Then total energy becomes kinetic energy also.

Answer (score -2):

Total Energy of the photon being considered for energy calculation

Comment: OP is asking about the energy for an *electron*, not a photon.